# iPhone speech recognition API?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

The new iPhone 3GS has support for voice commands, stuff like "call Bill" or "play music by the strokes" and whatnot.

I was looking through the iPhone SDK, but I cannot find any references to this capability.  All of the search keywords I choose seem to only find the new voice chat functionality.

Does anyone know whether Apple has added voice command APIs to the SDK, or whether it's yet another forbidden API?  If it does exist, could someone point a particular class out to me?

Comment: What is the voice chat capability? Is there an API hook for TTS? I've been looking for that.

Comment: Apparently there's not (other than the accessibility stuff).  The voice chat stuff is new.  It's specifically for allowing two iPhone users to speak with each other over a data stream. It's designed for use in games.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SDK does not support either voice recognition or text to speech. Voice recognition is only available through the Voice control app, and text to speech is only available through the accessibility APIs when accessibility is turned on.

Answer (score 16):

[OpenEars](http://www.politepix.com/openears/) is a really nice Objective-C API for CMU Sphinx. Worth checking out if you want to incorporate CMU Sphinx in your app.

Answer (score 4):

One could try to bundle [poketsphinx](https://cmusphinx.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/cmusphinx/branches/pocketsphinx-0.6/pocketsphinx/) speech recognition library from the [CMU Sphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/) project. It is a open source
large vocabulary, speaker-independent continuous speech recognition
engine. Chech the [README](https://cmusphinx.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/cmusphinx/branches/pocketsphinx-0.6/pocketsphinx/README) to see how to set up in XCode.

Comment: I wrote a wrapper for pocket sphinx that helps setup as well:  http://github.com/KingOfBrian/VocalKit/

Comment: Hi brian do you have any example which uses VocalKit if so please share it with me.thanks in adv.