# Speech recognition in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone

Is there any via which we can identify the speech saved by the user at any time.what i want to do i want to save some user voices in the iphone and when user call any one sound iphone should react on that way i.e like if i say camera it would open the camera and if i say gallry it would open the photo gallery.

Is there any API provided by apple in any SDK upto 4.0 beta.or we have to use any third party tool for it .

Thanks

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121548/iphone-speech-recognition-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no api as far as i know... Overall iPhone isn't a kind of device you want to do such things on, in terms of performance at least. The regular scheme to do speech recognition on the iphone is to sample the mic, send the recorded stuff onto server, and fetch the result.