# speech to text is not working

Tags: iphone, speech-recognition

i m searching for a long time but i m unable to find API for speech-to-text in iphone.
even i got some thing in NSSpeechRecognizer but it's framework appkit.framework is not available  in xcode but it is in mac os. 
so i m unable to use NSSpeechRecognizer class what is the problem i m not getting...

if some body has plz tell about that API who can convert speech to text......

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone speech recognition API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121548/iphone-speech-recognition-api)

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this, but check [Vocal Kit](http://github.com/KingOfBrian/VocalKit) by Brian King. Read more [here](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2010/05/vocalkit-shim-for-speech-recognition-on-iphone/). It is created with [Carnegie Mellon University's (CMU) Sphinx project](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: vocal kit is not good at speech-to-text but OpenEars is good.